# One activity with fragments and a navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

So, I want to build an app that has only one `activity` and will use `multiple fragments`. I have a log in activity, and after I make the log in I go to my `maintactivity` that has a fragment and a `view-pager` so I can swipe through some fragments(this fragments will be like a day of a calendar). My navigation drawer will be used to open other fragments, no the same as the ones mentioned before. My issues are, after I apply the view-pager, my button to open the drawer doesn't work and my fragments doesn't change when I click in the navigation drawer items, is keeps the fragment on top (I open it with the slide movement, since the button doesn't work). Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
package amsi.dei.estg.ipleiria.pt.projeto;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 5;
    private ViewPager mPager;
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

//since I have two onBackPressed, on for the drawer and other for my pageview, I left the one I thought would be more useful.

    /*@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
            // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            // Otherwise, select the previous step.
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    }*/

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return new Dia();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }

    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fragment = null;

        if(id==R.id.nav_dia)
        {
            fragment = new Dia();
        }
        else if(id==R.id.nav_meusAlimentos)
        {
            fragment = new MeusAlimentos();
        }
        else if(id==R.id.nav_login)
        {
            Intent login = new Intent(this, LogIn.class);
            startActivity(login);
        }

        if(fragment != null){
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

            ft.replace(R.id.screen_area, fragment);

            ft.commit();

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="amsi.dei.estg.ipleiria.pt.projeto.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/screen_area"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Dia.java

```
package amsi.dei.estg.ipleiria.pt.projeto;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by nelsu on 24/11/2017.
 */

public class Dia extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        getActivity().setTitle("Day");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootview = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dia_content, container, false);
        return  rootview;
        //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dia_content, null);
    }

}
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="amsi.dei.estg.ipleiria.pt.projeto.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

activity_dia_content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false">
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle_dia_macros"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="gráficos e percentagem das macros"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_dia_refeicao"
                android:text="Pequeno Almoço" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_dia_refeicao"
                android:text="Café da manhã" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_dia_refeicao"
                android:text="Almoço" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_dia_refeicao"
                android:text="Lanche" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_dia_refeicao"
                android:text="Jantar" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle_dia_refeicao"
                android:text="Lanche da noite" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

nav_header_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label_nome_user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com" />

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_dia"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:title="Dia" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_meusAlimentos"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Meus Alimentos" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_login"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
            android:title="Login" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Tools" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_about"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="About" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_quit"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:title="Quit" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write your own code for this.
here is a nice library for your problem with all required things.

https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare

Comment: thanks but half of that code is like chinese to me, Im kinda new to android I cant adapt that to my project...

Comment: also, I doesnt open new fragment on click with the navigation drawer buttons